# Is there such thing as a VideoField in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

So I have been making a site recently, and I want a way for people to upload videos and for me to display them, just like I do with an `ImageField`. However I have found that `VideoField` is not a thing. I have used `FileField` so far, and it is uploading to the right folder, however I don't know how to display that video like an `ImageField`.

I want to use something specifically made for video files, but so far I have't found anything online about VideoFiles.

Here is my model.

```py
class Post(models.Model):
    # ... other things here
    video_file = models.FileField(upload_to='post_files',blank=True,null=True)
```

So my question is: is there a `VideoFile` in Django?

Comment: There isn't such a field built in to Django, what would you like from such a field?

Comment: I want users to be able to upload videos, and for me to display them in the post. So for example, if this is a line in my models
`
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='post_files',blank=True,null=True)
`
I can use `{% post.image.url %}` or whatever, and it will display the image. However I want to do this for videos.

Comment: There is nothing stopping you from using s FileField for this. Having a video play on your page can be as simple as including a `video` tag with the file url as the source.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. There is no `VideoField` in Django.
2. You can use `FileField` for sure.

In your template just add the following:

```
<video width="500px" height="500px" controls>
     <source src="{{ post.video_file.url }}" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

In addition of Priyanshu answer's, if you need to display mp4 in Django admin you can use this code :

```
class MyVideoAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('id', 'video_tag', 'comment', )

    def video_tag(self, obj):
        if obj.video:
            return format_html('<a href="{}">Link to video</a><video height="200px" controls><source src="{}" type="video/mp4"></video>'.format(obj.video.url, obj.video.url))
    video_tag.short_description = 'Video'

admin.site.register(MyVideo, MyVideoAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with [django-embed-video](https://github.com/jazzband/django-embed-video). It's for beginner-intermediate devs who want to play around with videos on their project.